# Where should I put static files in my shared hosting account?

Tags: javascript, html, cpanel

I tried putting the JS file in `public_html`, where I also put my CSS, but than it only shows the JS code.

I also cannot find any tutorial as to where do put any files and wanted to ask before I do something that will harm my site.

Should I make a new file and change the url in my HTML to the new folder?

[image: Picture of my files in cPanel]

Comment: Can you update with screenshot of folder structure of `public_html`?

Comment: I only put the index.html and index.css in, so there is nothing inside except this. Should I make separate folders for html, css and js?

Comment: It is good practice to put css and js in respective folders, the index.html will be directly in the `public_html` folder. But I did not get this statement of yours - "I tried putting it in public_html, where I also put my CSS, but than it only shows the JS code."

Comment: Now it works!! Thank you! So I should only put the index.html straight inside and add other name.html in a separate html folder? And also pictures in a separate folder inside public_html?

Comment: Usually index.html would be the main file requested when your website is visited. The other html files can be placed wherever you require, depends on your site and url structure.

Answer (score 0):

[Anurag Srivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944809/where-to-put-js-files-in-cpanel#comment96652402_54944809) said:

> It is good practice to put css and js in respective folders, the
>   index.html will be directly in the public_html folder. But I did not
>   get this statement of yours - "I tried putting it in public_html,
>   where I also put my CSS, but than it only shows the JS code."

So I will put every css and js file in separate folders inside public_html, only index.html goes straight inside public_html

Comment: Thanks! May I also ask, this post got a new title, but I think the old title was better because noobs like me are never going to write this into google and find this, if they ever wanted, as I didn't when I was browsing.